# Fine joystick library control

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am leaning the [ROSLiB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roslib) library and I am using the [NG-Joystick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-joystick) virtual joystick library to issue twist instructions to a TurtleSim robot.

My problem is when I use the joystick to move the robot, it lurches around widely which is not acceptable for the TurtleSim and certainly not acceptable for moving a real robot. Below is a screen shot of the effects I'm experiencing.

[image: image description]

If you look at the console area on the left of the image, you would see the raw X & Y coordinates I am directly publishing to *turtle1/cmd_vel*. The right side part of the image shows the erratic effect of those coordinates. The section of my code for publishing those coordinates are simple enough but I thought I'd include it below:

```
this.joystickComp.joystickMove$.subscribe(d => {
      console.log(d);
      console.log('X: ' + d.pointerPos.x + ', Y: ' + d.pointerPos.y);
      console.log('sending cmd_vel ...');
      this.rosService.move(d.pointerPos.x, d.pointerPos.y);
      console.log('cmd_vel sent');
});
```

Can anyone advice how I can get better control ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358605/fine-joystick-library-control/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are really sending a twist message, you should work on your units. Note that ROS uses SI-units. You are asking (at least according to the log) for 450+ m/s translational velocity and 310+ rad/s rotational velocity.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-04**:
Makes for some nice spirograph renders though ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-04**:
For the OP: [REP-103: Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#units).

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-08-04**:
Thank you both for your answers. I especially appreciate the link, @gvdhoorn.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-08-04**:
To be clear (because this is not my strong point), I'm dividing the x & y values by 100.
The control is far more reasonable but if I'm still incorrect, I would appreciate your feedback

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-04**:
What I would suggest is to define a minimum and maximum velocity (linear and rotational), map that to the minimum and maximum pixel positions of your joystick (in both dimensions), and then define a (linear) mapping between those two ranges.

That would allow you to use proper units for your minimum and maximum velocities, instead of fudging with a factor to get pixel positions in "the right range".